# Is this statement true that Java 8 provides functional style but is not functional programming?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Is this statement true that Java 8 provides functional style but is not functional programming as the syntax which it uses is also an object?

```
 Calculator calc = (i, j) ->  i/j;
```

If yes, then why we get articles everywhere Functional Programming with Java 8?

Comment: The "functions" are syntactic sugar on top of normal Java. So, it's not a built-in capability - Java still doesn't have first class functions. It has functional programming-*like* features and properties. But lambdas aren't functions. You can employ some function programming paradigms and constructs (e.g., `Optional` is a very typical FP concept) and you can mix FP and OO functionality (e.g., use your `DBConnectionManager` to access a database but then read your records as `Stream<DBRecord>` and operate on that stream). It's still OO first with FP features thrown in.

Comment: What you implement here is a method which takes two int arguments and returns a double. So, your implementation represents a function. Moreover, java8 supports main functional programming concepts such as functions as first class citizens, immutability, pure functions with no side effects and so on. So in my opinion java8 supports functional programming though internal implementation is based on OOP concepts.

Comment: might be helpful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101352/is-functional-programming-possible-in-java

Comment: People tend to distort concepts. Compare "Java adopts some functional concepts" (which is true), "Java is built upon some functional concepts" (which is not really true), "Java is a functional language" (which is false). If there is a title "Functional Programming with Java 8", the author should explain what they mean by "functional programming" otherwise it's too broad (as your question is) and inaccurate. Why do you care, by the way?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a (non-exhaustive) list of abstract FP concepts:

1. Focus on immutability
2. Referential transparency for functions
3. Limitations on side effects (follows from 1 & 2)
4. Expression-based, no statements. Statements are not first-class.
5. Functions as first-class values.
6. State changes as first-class values (e.g. Clojure atoms).
7. Algebraic Data Types as fundamental units.
8. Enforcing some or all of the above via the type system.

And I could go on. A language doesn't have to tick every box on the list to be a "Functional Programming Language" (I can't actually think of any that meet *all* of those bullet points), but the more boxes it ticks the less qualification you have to give to give it that label. And that's why Java doesn't qualify in the eyes of many functional programmers: it just doesn't check off very many (arguably only one) of the above items.

Which is not to say that you *cannot* do functional programming in Java, but it's hard. The language gives you too few of the tools you need to work with, meaning you'll have to write a lot of boilerplate to encode the necessary primitives as classes, meaning your code will be slower and harder to follow (and that's before you get into the issue of 15 different competing ad-hoc library implementations of those primitives).

You can treat your objects as immutable, favor expressions over statements (like using the ternary operator instead of if/else), make most of your methods pure functions, go hog-wild with lambdas, etc. but at the end of the day there's still a lot of friction, both with the language and the expectations of the community.